# upgrading joomla 2.5.28 to 3.x makes many errors

Tags: joomla, upgrade

my joomla language is persian
I put the error on maximum and disabled remember me component
but when I try to upgrade joomla, after 86% forwarding, a blank page with a php error appears
then I can't access any part of my admin section
please give me a link to shows a step by step upgrading joomla.
many links I found but not help full

Comment: What exactly is the PHP error displaying? Maybe that can help us to help you! reading errormessages is important. Please post the message here.

Comment: each menu has different error,and some pages shows one and some shows two line of error
most of errors is about controllers

Comment: If you need, I can give you the Cpanel and joomla admin panel user and pass. I must do it as soon as possible for my customer.Please HELP me